# Java Adding something to ArrayList then searching for that item again not working

Tags: java

I am trying to create an array of id strings that have already been used to prevent duplications. If the ID does not exist in the array, I add it to the usedID array so next time an id is scanned, if it already exists in the array it won't accepted = false. But that does not seem to be the case. Help?

```
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> ID = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> usedID = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean accepted;

    File file = new File("C:/Embarq/purchasedList.txt");
    if (file.exists()) {

        try {
            list = (ArrayList<String>) Files.readAllLines(file.toPath(), Charset.defaultCharset());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
        if (list.isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }

        for (String line : list) {
            String[] res = line.split(";");
            ID.add(res[2]);
        }

        if (ID.contains(jTextField1.getText())) {
            if (usedID.contains(jTextField1.getText())) {
                accepted = false;
            } else {
                accepted = true;
                usedID.add(jTextField1.getText());
            }
        } else {
            accepted = false;
        }
        if (accepted) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Accepted");
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Denied");
        }

        jTextField1.setText("");
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "purchasedList.txt does not exist!");
    }
}
```

pardon the ugly code..

Comment: The solution to this dilema: **do some debugging.** So, on that note, what have you done to debug the code? Have you used logging? println statements? It's time to dig down into how the code reacts to the data to find out why things aren't working.

Comment: Where do you have those lines of code? Just trying to make sure that not everything is in one method? Also what kind data do you have and for what value is it not working?

Answer (score 1):

Each time this code run, you create a new `usedID`, so everything that was there on the previous run is lost. You need to keep the usedID between calls.

Note that you should consider using `HashSet` instead of `ArrayList`, with `ArrayList` every check will be `O(n)`, while with `HashSet` it will be `O(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

So just create an object that does this for you:

```
public class MyArrayList extends ArrayList<String>{
    @Override
    public boolean add(String id){
        if(!this.contains(id))
            return super.add(id);
        // else you shouldn't add, so the ArrayList isn't modified, return false
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now when you create your `userID` in your main method, use this class instead of `ArrayList`:

```
final ArrayList<String> userID = new MyArrayList();
```

Comment: If you are going to subclass ArrayList to change the insertion behaviour, you should override all methods that insert elements (like `add(int index, E element)`, `addAll(Collection<? extends E> c)` and `addAll(int index, Collection<? extends E> c)`. Also your solution does not solve the problem (check my answer).

Comment: @fbafelipe I understand that you _should_ do those things (along with constructors), but if you know this is all you are going to use, then this is a quick and easy way to accomplish it (without writing inline code all over the place).  I can see the argument that a static method which takes an `ArrayList` might be more appropriate here.  As for solving "the problem", it's not clear to me exactly what the problem is.  The OP asked how to ensure that you don't add duplicates, so that's what I answered.

Comment: But someone else could change the code that use your class and thats not the behaviour that person would expect. Also, why would you bother writing that class when the java api already contains a class (HashSet) that does exactly the same thing (but is consistent with the other methos)?

Comment: @fbafelipe I understand your complaints and they are very valid (depending on what this is for).  I don't think a hash table is necessarily the best option--it depends.  If you need to quickly know whether or not the set contains the String id, then I agree with a hash table.  On the other hand, if your main use is going to be iterating over the id's, then an array-type structure (e.g. `ArrayList`) is more appropriate.

Comment: I have tried the .add() method before but that does not seem to work. The point of this snippet of code is when someone enters an id, it checks if it exists, if it does it then checks to see if the id has already been used. that is where I'm having trouble. no matter how many times I enter the same ID it won't catch it as being used more than once.

Comment: The variable `usedID` is set to an `ArrayList` containing zero elements.  Of course it doesn't contain any ID's until you add to it.  Where are you populating the `usedID` `ArrayList`?  I really think your problem is that you aren't keeping an `ArrayList` object to hold the used IDs, similar to what @fbafelipe has said.